# Explorer Context Menus

Tags: c#, registry, installation, contextmenu

I have just coded an application in C# using Visual Basic 2010, has taken me quite a while as I ave little experience with C# however after much learning I seem to have got by so far, I am currently coding an application that will allow a user to simply right-click on any image type, this will then open up the Explorer Context Menu and a new item will appear, "Upload to Website". With this, I want it to communicate with my application (by passing a command?) to then run a function I have wrote with the WebClient UploadClass.

The only problem I am having is how to actually do that, I want to go down the registry key route, I have done some extensive research into that and weighed it up against Shell and third-parties, and I believe it is the most suitable option for what I am trying to do. I know how to set registry keys in C#, however the one thing I am baffled on is where I am to set the registry keys and how exactly I can make them communicate with my application.

I am really looking at being pointed in the right direction, also I have a few questions to ask.

When I come to actually setting the keys, where is my application stored? I don't want the menus to become corrupt or have missing commands, I have looked in the Program Files folder in my main drive however the application isn't actually there, it is using the OneClick installer provided with Visual Studio 2010 to install.

Finally, how can I make my application understand comments, for example if I passed:

```
C:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /u "%1
```

Where /u is the command for upload and %1 the file location, how can I code my application to understand it needs to run the upload function when its commanded?

Any help or ideas would be hugely appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** I have been looking into getting the registry key side of things complete and I have delved into the registry, I have decided to use a third-party application installer as it simply gives me more room to provide what I want to do, such as expanding my project further. I am using the [Inno](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) set up compiler to do this, and with it comes powerful tools to easily set some registry values, which I can use for my contextual-menu.

I am currently however, finding it hard to make sense of the registry. Firstly, what keys do I need to set to associate my program with filetypes such as .png, .gif? A simple entry "Upload with SoftwareName" in their explorer context menus is all I am after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to create a new context menu item for explorer. This is achievable by adding registry keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT depending on which files you want your application to appear on file/folder right click. Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer) example.

As for communicating with your program, the key you will set in the registry will be in the format you showed in your question. This will basically open your program with /u filename arguments. In order to read the arguments when your application opens you will need to iterate over [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) which contains all the opening command lines. Then based on what these are you can execute the methods you want.

Comment: Thank you I will be looking into both of the links you have provided!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever installer you use, it will know where the application is going to be installed, and should create the registry values accordingly. As for the commandline arguments: you have to evaluate the arguments and call the respective function. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for an introduction.

Comment: Thing is the application is one of the "ClickOnce" applications which VS2010 generates, and personally I don't have much control over where it is installed and what is installed. Infact, if the user has the required requisites to run the program, theres absolutely no installation necessary, so I am slightly confused haha.  Thank you for the CLI Arguments, I will look into them!